# Por que si un método usa una interfaz como parámetro, al llamar a dicho método desde otra clase hay que implementar dicha interfaz?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un método que usa una interfaz `AsyncReponseHttpSending` como argumento, el problema es que al llamar a dicho método desde otra clase tengo que implementar dicha interfaz en esta clase, pero sin embargo en la clase padre de dicho método no se implementa. La interfaz solo tiene un método `public void onHttpResult(int httpCode, String httpMessage, String body)` . También agradecería que me corrigieran en la manera de llamar a dicho método dado que al llamarlo no se me ejecuta. Gracias de antemano

Clase del método

```
public class HttpSending {

 private HttpSending() {

    }
    //Método que quiero llamar
    public static void sendHttpPost(final AsyncReponseHttpSending delegate, final String urlString, final Object data) {
        new Thread(TAG) {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                OutputStream dos = null;

                int httpCode = HttpConstants.HTTP_UNKNOWN;
                String httpMessage = "";

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpUrlConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
                    httpUrlConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ);

                    httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

                    dos = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
                    dos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
                    dos.flush();

                    httpCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    httpMessage = httpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage();
                    Log.debug(TAG + "Http to : " + urlString + ". Response code: " + httpCode + " Respuesta: " + httpMessage);
                    dos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                } finally {
                    if (dos != null) {
                        try {
                            dos.close();
                        } catch (Exception ignored){}
                    }
                    delegate.onHttpResult(httpCode, httpMessage, null);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Clase donde quiero usar y llamo a dicho método

```
public class HttpPost implements AsyncReponseHttpSending {

    private static final String TAG = "HttpPosting: ";


    public void postRequests() {

        Log.info(TAG + "algoooo");
       final String url = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
        JsonArray data = null;
        HttpSending.sendHttpPost(this,url,data);



    }

    private String IDProbe = "353627076313132";
    private int probePhone = 626716205;


    @Override
    public void onHttpResult(int httpCode, String httpMessage, String body) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que creo es importante tener en cuenta la definición de interfaz 
"La interfaz es una clase abstracta pura, es decir,
 una clase donde se indican los métodos, pero no se implementa ninguno.
 Permite al programador establecer una estructura que ha de seguir toda clase que implemente esta interfaz. 
 En la interfaz solo se indica los nombres de los métodos, sus parámetros y tipos que retornan, pero no el código de cada método."

con respecto al titulo de la pregunta la respuesta sería

Tú llamado al metodo sendHttpPost de la clase HttpSending te pide tres parametros que son de tipo:
1.- AsyncReponseHttpSending
2.- String urlString
3.- Object

Donde AsyncReponseHttpSending es una interfaz, es por ello que al realizar el llamado de tu metodo sendHttpPost
debes pasarle un objeto de este tipo, para poder pasarle este valor también se pudo haber hecho de la siguiente forma:

```
public void postRequests() {
        final String url = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
        JsonArray data = null;
        AsyncReponseHttpSending miInterfaz = new AsyncReponseHttpSending() {
            @Override
            public void onHttpResult(int httpCode, String httpMessage, String body) {
                 Log.d("Respuesta",""+ body);
            }
        };
        HttpSending.sendHttpPost(miInterfaz,url,data);
}
```

si te das cuenta es lo mismo que si la clase HttpPost implemente  AsyncReponseHttpSending y sobreescriba el metodo onHttpResult
de esa forma en lugar de mandarle la variable de tipo AsyncReponseHttpSending haces referencia a this.

En conclusión sería , que se debe de implementar los metodos donde tengas tu clase anonima, pero en la clase donde 
la recibes como parametro ya solo haces uso de la estructura definida en ella por ejemplo en la linea  delegate.onHttpResult(httpCode, httpMessage, null);.
En tu caso creaste la interfaz para usarla como un handler para recibir la respuesta de una petición?

Con respecto a tu segunda duda de que no se ejecuta. 
Lo probe corriendo  tu metodo postRequests y debugueando truena en el parseo de los datos pero si se ejecuta y entra al método onHttpResult pintando el log. Puedes indicar que es lo que no se esta ejecutando ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, ya lo he resuelto, como bien dices saltaba el error en el parseo de datos, el error era de null en el objeto data dado que null no se puede llevar a String. Una vez más gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Para arrancar te dejo la definición de interfaz: [Definición interfaz java](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_(Java))

Contestando tu pregunta: La interfaz tiene que ser implementada por definición.

Para que necesitas llamar al método onHttpResult?